# SUPEE 8788 file 0 created in root directory

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-8788

In PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2016-10-11-07-03-46.sh, an empty file 0 is created in the Magento root directory. Should this be deleted? What's it's purpose?